# SharePoint Online - Move document library contents (files and folders)

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, copy, move

In SharePoint Online I have some subsites on site collection A and I need to move the contents (folders and files) on these subsites to site collection B.

I am trying to avoid using a 3rd party tool, is there a PowerShell script I can use to move the subsites or is there a script to move the contents (folders and files) from site collection A to site collection B?

Ideally I would also like to preserve the version history.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint online provided such built-in feature to move/copy file/folders to another place.

- [Move or copy files in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/move-or-copy-files-in-sharepoint-00e2f483-4df3-46be-a861-1f5f0c1a87bc)

BR

Comment: Thank you I am aware of the GUI Move To function but the problem is I have hundreds of sites, so I would need a way to automate this somehow via script

Comment: You can have a try pnp powershell:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/move-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps